# Show block on /user profile page only

Tags: 7, users, blocks

I want to show a block when a user visits his/her own profile page at /user. 
The public user profiles have paths of "/member/[username]".

When I limit the block to "user" it won't show up. When I limit it to "member/*" it will show up both on the own profile and on the public profiles.

Is the "user" url something special?

Comment: It also works for "user/*" which makes me think the internal alias for the `user` page is actually `user/[uid]`...might have to resort to PHP for this one :/

Comment: `return arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2);` will do the trick

Comment: @Clive As usual dropping the FIRE in comments =D

Comment: @Clive, just wanted to give you further props for this answer. One year later, and I found this page again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @clive has mentioned is great if you want to use `/user` for this, but from a number of angles, I really don't like using it at all for this kind of thing.  I would like to say mostly from a style perspective, but actually more from a linking perspective, eg, an email or post that includes `check out my cool profile on mototribe:  www.mototribe.com/user` bollixing things up.

So, when I've done stuff like this, I include php logic in my block view along the lines of:

```
$global $user;
$block=array();
$node=menu_get_object();

if ($node->type==THENODETYPEWEARELOOKINGFOR && $node->uid==$user->uid) {
  // generate the block here
} else {
  // don't generate anything (or put something else in it's place)
}

return $block;
```

so the block is only generated when the currently logged in user looks at a certain node type that s/he owns.  Obviously I've not fleshed out all the isset()s or empty()s needed in prime time for the above but I am sure you get the jist.

Of course, I could also be talking total smack here if D7 user profiles aren't nodes, but this works great in D6 with content profiles :)

Comment: that's a great point and a reason to not use /user. I guess I can use some PHP to check if the logged in user is looking at his/her own profile to show the extra block. Thanks

Comment: Combination of yours and Clive's code: global $user;
return arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2) && $user->uid == arg(1); Thanks again!!!